# What is happening with resistors in series/parallel at the base of a BJT?

Tags: resistors, bjt, base

[image: diagram]
<sub>(source: [subefotos.com](https://fotos.subefotos.com/05f069ab13a562a4ef114b33d5e84a5do.png))</sub>

R1 receives 5 volts from the Arduino, but with a low current.  The BJT is used to amplify the current.  Every example I have seen of this does not have the R2 in that way. What is the R2 doing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's most likely a pull-down resistor to guarantee that the transistor remains off during the MCU's power-up. The value was chosen so as not to steal too much of the base current. I don't know that it's necessary, but having it won't hurt anything.